# How to specify a double order by expression using sub part of field name

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

fairly new coming to  lamabda/linq stuff.

I have a directory with a number of files in it.

I want to group and order all these files based on sub-parts of the name of the file.

So, for instance I have these files:

```
group1.01,001.dat
group1.01.102.dat
group1.01.086.dat

group2.03,101.dat
group2.02.002.dat
group2.01.016.dat
```

and I want a result like this:

```
group1.01,001.dat
group1.01.086.dat
group1.01.102.dat
```

---

```
group2.01.016.dat
group2.02.002.dat
group2.03,101.dat
```

Now, I have managed to group my files OK, just not the order of them.

Note: the order is defined in order by ss and then by fff where the format of the file is:

groupname.ss.fff.dat

So, to get the groups I have this code:

```
var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(min, "*.dat")
.Select(s => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s))
.GroupBy(s => (s.Split('.'))[0]).ToList();
```

which works fine. I thought by adding this would complete the job for me:

```
var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(min, "*.dat")
.Select(s => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s))
.GroupBy(s => (s.Split('.'))[0])
.OrderBy(s=> (s.Split('.'))[1] && s.Split('.'))[2]).ToList();
```

which does not compile.  What do I need to do please?

Comment: As a side note: it might be easier to use LINQ syntax here (rather than just the underlying extension methods); the compiler syntax makes multiple order conditions simple.

Comment: @MarcGravell HI, thanks for posting. i am new to this.  would you be able to provide a sample? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify secondary sort criteria, use [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(min, "*.dat")
    .Select(fileName => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName))
    .OrderBy(name => name.Split('.')[1])
    .ThenBy(name => name.Split('.')[2])
    .GroupBy(name => name.Split('.')[0])
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key) // Note: g is an IGrouping<string, string>
    .ToList();
```

This code sorts by the secondary criteria *before* grouping, taking advantage of the fact that `GroupBy` preserves the original order of items in the sequence. It then groups and orders by the first component of the names.

Here's an alternate solution using LINQ query syntax:

```
var result =
    from fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(min, "*.dat")
    let name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
    let parts = name.Split('.')
    orderby parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]
    group name by parts[0] into g
    select g;
```

This code is slightly different in that it calls `name.Split('.')` only once, and does all the ordering before the final grouping.

Comment: HI, that worked. Thank you very much.  This has been very educational to me!

Comment: I have bookmarked this as one of my favorite answers. Thanks again!